# Send FormData object AND an additional parameter via ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, form-data

I have managed to send a FormData object like so:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', this.files[0]);
$.ajax({
   url: urlUploadProductsFile,
   type: 'POST',
   data: formData,
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false
}, 'json');
```

Now what I want to do is add an additional `CustomerId` to send to the server. The following won't work:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', this.files[0]);
$.ajax({
   url: urlUploadProductsFile,
   type: 'POST',
   data: { "file": formData, "CustomerId": 2 },
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false
}, 'json');
```

And I also tried the following variations:

`data: { "file": formData, "CustomerId": 2 }, processData: true`

`data: JSON.stringify({ "file": formData, "CustomerId": 2 })`

`data: { "file": JSON.stringify(formData), "CustomerId": 2 }`

`data: { file: formData, CustomerId: 2 }`

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', this.files[0]);
formData.append('CustomerId', 2);

/*
 note:: appending in form Data will give "csrf token mismatch error". 
 so better you make a input feild of type hidden with name = CustomerId 
 and value =  2 
*/ 

$.ajax({
   url: urlUploadProductsFile,
   type: 'POST',
   data: formData,
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false
}, 'json');
```

Comment: what if the secondary data was not a simple type like 2?  What if I also needed to send a json object?  How would I encode it in the front end, and how would I unencode it in the controller?

Comment: JSON is a simple string. You can escape it as pointed there: https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html

> The following characters are reserved in JSON and must be properly escaped to be used in strings:

Backspace is replaced with \b

Form feed is replaced with \f

Newline is replaced with \n

Carriage return is replaced with \r

Tab is replaced with \t

Double quote is replaced with \"

Backslash is replaced with \\

Comment: For anyone coming here in the future, the extra parameters I added were put in the `params` object of `req` (request).

Answer (score 2):

You need to either add it directly to `formData` (just as you did with `'file'`), or alternatively use query (GET) parameters.