# How to request several arguments from FormData?

Tags: python, ajax, flask, request, form-data

This is a follow-up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428329/how-to-upload-a-file-and-populate-parts-of-the-website-with-its-content): there I learned how to upload a file, process it and then populate the website again with its content using `AJAX` and `FormData`. For example, if I have a file `data.csv` like this:

```
A,B,C
1,3,4
2,4,2
```

I can pass it using `AJAX` and `FormData`

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm">
    <div class="custom-file">
       <input id="myfile" name="myfile" type="file" class="custom-file-input">

       <label for="myfile" class="custom-file-label">
         Choose file...
       </label>
    </div>
</form>

// the javascript part
var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];
var formdata = new FormData(form);

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: "/_get_table",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                timeout: 600000,
```

and get:

[image]

I can then easily fetch this using

```
file = request.files['myfile']
```

and convert it into a dataframe using

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
```

**My question is now** how I would do this, if I want to pass additional parameters (not only the file). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448724/send-formdata-object-and-an-additional-parameter-via-ajax) it is suggested to use

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("myform", form)
formdata.append("myvalue", 10)
```

which gives

[image]

and the `headers`

[image]

**How do I now collect the info correctly?** I can get `myvalue` like this

```
val = request.form['myvalue']
```

but I have not found a way to access and read `myfile`. If I e.g. try

```
file = request.files['myform']
```

I get

> werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap..newcls: 400 Bad
>   Request: KeyError: 'myform'

I also tried other solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664376/1534017) but without success.

Comment: Please show us your whole request including headers. And btw it doesn't look correct as you shouldn't put `form` in to your `formdata` but only the `myfile`. Your payload should consist of `myfile` and `myvalue`. As you can see in your screenshot. `myform` is obviously not a file but a javascript object. That's meaningless.

Comment: @Sraw: Yes, but I don't know how to pass it correctly; I don't know how to only extract the file. I also tried `form.elements.myfile` but that does not help either. Give me a sec to make the screenshots...

Comment: @Sraw; I added the screenshot of the headers. Does that help?

Comment: Yes it does help. So your format is correct. The only problem is how to pass file correctly in javascript. In this case this is not a python problem. I guess you can directly `var formdata = new FormData(form); formdata.append("myvalue", 10)`.

Comment: @Sraw: That seems to work! Feel free to add it as an answer. I will then later open another question to really understand this behavior...

Comment: @Sraw: Could you still add your solution as an answer?! I will then upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you didn't add your file to the `FormData` correctly.

As you are using `multipart/form-data`, your payload should be one file and some `form-data`. But in your screenshot, as you can see, you were adding one `object`.

To solve this problem, actually you can directly add your value to the original `FormData`:

```
var formdata = new FormData(form); 
formdata.append("myvalue", 10);
```