# Send multiple parameters when axios upload image

Tags: symfony, vuejs2, axios

I'm uploading images with formdata and axios. I'm using symfony for my back end and I need to access my image file and other parameter both. This is my axios code.

```
axios.post(testUp, { data: formData, ad: 12 }, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                }).then(response => {

                });
```

And here is my symfony code.

```
/**
 * @Route("/test_up", name="test_up", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function testUp(Request $request, CarRepository $carRepository) {
    dd($request->files->all());
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting null as output. I'm getting the formdata from image uploaded and it's a formdata object. It works if I do this but need both parameters.

```
axios.post(testUp, formData, {
                 headers: {
                     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                 }
             }).then(response => {
                 alert('*');
                 console.log(response);
             });
```

**but I need to send other parameter too.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant mix FormData with JSON. It is related question

> [Send FormData object AND an additional parameter via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448724/send-formdata-object-and-an-additional-parameter-via-ajax)

If you have only one parameter - ad = 12 I recommend to use code:

```
axios.post(testUp + "?" + (new URLSearchParams({ad: 12})).toString()
, formData, {
                 headers: {
                     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                 }
             }).then(response => {
                 alert('*');
                 console.log(response);
             });
```

Answer (score 1):

On Symfony side you should use a form so you can receive many type of data. See documentation here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

On vuejs/axios side, you just cant send json content AND form data content at the same time (as it is 2 different type of data). But you can add some content to your form data (just like you can have a file with other fields in your Symfony form).